# Asynchronous web services problem

Tags: java, webservice-client

i need one answer. I am calling Asynchronous web services and ofcourse it want Asynchronous response. Must webservice somehow call my client or how is implemented response.

I read this and many other pages but i do not know if web service need to call me back for response.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/web-interfaces/111-asynchronous-web-services-with-jboss-ws.html

regards

Answer (score 2):

You need to think it as a 3rd party service which you dont have any access to its source. 
You need to handle asyn calls yourself for your side.

java.util.concurrent package contains what you want
see below link

http://www.scribd.com/doc/17369778/Java-Concurrent-Package-tutorial